# SSRS - stop RunningValue when encountering null

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I have a table in SSRS that graphs cumulative amount spent for fiscal years 2019 and 2020. Fiscal year starts in Oct and ends in Sept.

[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRRUd.png)

Values: `=RunningValue(Fields!total_cost.Value, Sum, "fiscal_year")`

Category Groups: `month`

Series Groups: `fiscal_year`

The table has rows for all months (Oct-Sept) in FY19 but only some months (Oct-Feb) in FY20. However, when I try to plot both FY19 and FY20 in the same graph, because rest of FY20 data is incomplete, the RunningValue maintains the same value after February.

What I'm looking for is a way to stop RunningValue once it encounters a null value (in March) so that the resulting graph looks more like this:

[Expected Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klu59.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely untested but you could try something like this

```
=IIF(
    IsNothing(Fields!total_cost.Value), 
    Nothing, 
    RunningValue(Fields!total_cost.Value, Sum, "fiscal_year")
    )
```

This assumes NULL values rather than zeros, if you have zeros in the 'empty' datapoints then adjust accordingly.